# CSS/LESS translate with calc percent & pixels

Tags: css, less

I need to translate an element -50% + a certain fixed value.
So far I tried this in LESS:

```
transform: translateX(calc(~'(100% + 15px)'););
```

But the compiler tells me:

> "SyntaxtError: expected ')' got ';'

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: You have one to many ";" semicolons in your code example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that write an example

```
transform: translateX(calc(~'(100% + 15px)')); /* calc doesnt work on transform*/

so use 
transform: translateX(100%) translateX(+15px);
```

Comment: Wow, am I dumb or what? :) Thank you